# Custom (swappable) models for Django OAuth Toolkit

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I need to create custom Django OAuth Toolkit models.
I have an app with these models:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from oauth2_provider.models import (
    AbstractApplication, AbstractGrant,
    AbstractAccessToken, AbstractRefreshToken
)


class Application(AbstractApplication):
    GRANT_TYPES = (
        (AbstractApplication.GRANT_AUTHORIZATION_CODE, _("Authorization code")),
        (AbstractApplication.GRANT_IMPLICIT, _("Implicit")),
    )


class Grant(AbstractGrant):
    pass


class AccessToken(AbstractAccessToken):
    pass


class RefreshToken(AbstractRefreshToken):
    pass
```

And settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'oauth2_provider',
    ...
    'apps.oauth.apps.OauthConfig',
    ...
]

OAUTH2_PROVIDER_GRANT_MODEL = 'oauth.Grant'
OAUTH2_PROVIDER_APPLICATION_MODEL = 'oauth.Application'
OAUTH2_PROVIDER_ACCESS_TOKEN_MODEL = 'oauth.AccessToken'
OAUTH2_PROVIDER_REFRESH_TOKEN_MODEL = 'oauth.RefreshToken'
```

And when i trying to make migrations, i got this error:

```
ValueError: The field oauth2_provider.AccessToken.application was declared with a lazy reference to 'oauth.application', but app 'oauth' isn't installed.
The field oauth2_provider.AccessToken.source_refresh_token was declared with a lazy reference to 'oauth.refreshtoken', but app 'oauth' isn't installed.
The field oauth2_provider.Grant.application was declared with a lazy reference to 'oauth.application', but app 'oauth' isn't installed.
The field oauth2_provider.RefreshToken.access_token was declared with a lazy reference to 'oauth.accesstoken', but app 'oauth' isn't installed.
The field oauth2_provider.RefreshToken.application was declared with a lazy reference to 'oauth.application', but app 'oauth' isn't installed.
```

If i remove `OAUTH2_PROVIDER_***_MODEL` settings and run makemigrations again, i got many `fields.E304` and `fields.E305` errors:

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
oauth.AccessToken.application: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'AccessToken.application' clashes with reverse accessor for 'AccessToken.application'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'AccessToken.application' or 'AccessToken.application'.
oauth.AccessToken.source_refresh_token: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'AccessToken.source_refresh_token' clashes with reverse accessor for 'AccessToken.source_refresh_token'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'AccessToken.source_refresh_token' or 'AccessToken.source_refresh_token'.
oauth.AccessToken.source_refresh_token: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'AccessToken.source_refresh_token' clashes with reverse query name for 'AccessToken.source_refresh_token'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'AccessToken.source_refresh_token' or 'AccessToken.source_refresh_token'.
oauth.Grant.application: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Grant.application' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Grant.application'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Grant.application' or 'Grant.application'.
oauth.RefreshToken.access_token: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'RefreshToken.access_token' clashes with reverse accessor for 'RefreshToken.access_token'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'RefreshToken.access_token' or 'RefreshToken.access_token'.
oauth.RefreshToken.access_token: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'RefreshToken.access_token' clashes with reverse query name for 'RefreshToken.access_token'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'RefreshToken.access_token' or 'RefreshToken.access_token'.
oauth.RefreshToken.application: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'RefreshToken.application' clashes with reverse accessor for 'RefreshToken.application'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'RefreshToken.application' or 'RefreshToken.application'.
oauth2_provider.AccessToken.application: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'AccessToken.application' clashes with reverse accessor for 'AccessToken.application'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'AccessToken.application' or 'AccessToken.application'.
oauth2_provider.AccessToken.source_refresh_token: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'AccessToken.source_refresh_token' clashes with reverse accessor for 'AccessToken.source_refresh_token'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'AccessToken.source_refresh_token' or 'AccessToken.source_refresh_token'.
oauth2_provider.AccessToken.source_refresh_token: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'AccessToken.source_refresh_token' clashes with reverse query name for 'AccessToken.source_refresh_token'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'AccessToken.source_refresh_token' or 'AccessToken.source_refresh_token'.
oauth2_provider.Grant.application: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Grant.application' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Grant.application'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Grant.application' or 'Grant.application'.
oauth2_provider.RefreshToken.access_token: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'RefreshToken.access_token' clashes with reverse accessor for 'RefreshToken.access_token'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'RefreshToken.access_token' or 'RefreshToken.access_token'.
oauth2_provider.RefreshToken.access_token: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'RefreshToken.access_token' clashes with reverse query name for 'RefreshToken.access_token'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'RefreshToken.access_token' or 'RefreshToken.access_token'.
oauth2_provider.RefreshToken.application: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'RefreshToken.application' clashes with reverse accessor for 'RefreshToken.application'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'RefreshToken.application' or 'RefreshToken.application'.
```

Answer (score 0):

My friends and I did the following:
To override the classes used by the Django OAuth Toolkit is the
There are no settings like migrating and migrating:

```
OAUTH2_PROVIDER_APPLICATION_MODEL = 'oauth2_provider.Application'
OAUTH2_PROVIDER_REFRESH_TOKEN_MODEL = 'oauth2_provider.RefreshToken'
```

After running the migration remove or comment the variables mentioned above and put the variables
referring to the classes that needed to be overwritten, in our case it was as follows:

```
OAUTH2_PROVIDER_APPLICATION_MODEL = 'authentication.OAuthApplication'
OAUTH2_PROVIDER_GRANT_MODEL = 'authentication.OAuthGrant'
OAUTH2_PROVIDER_ACCESS_TOKEN_MODEL = 'authentication.OAuthAccessToken'
OAUTH2_PROVIDER_REFRESH_TOKEN_MODEL = 'authentication.OAuthRefreshToken'
```

In this link https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_topics.html#extending-the-application-model contains detailed information on why you need to do this process.